# Constructor for a non-generic subclass of a Collection

Tags: java, generics

This is something I should know, but I'm drawing a blank on it and am having a surprising amount of difficulty trying to find the answer with google.

I'm trying to extend a Java `Collection`, specifically the `ConcurrentHashMap`. I want to create my own hash map class for use with non-generic key/value pairs, specifically using my own classes.

So I've defined the class as such:

```
public class hashMap extends ConcurrentHashMap<class1, class2>
```

The issue is I'm forgetting how to properly write the constructor(s) so that they're non-generic. For instance, with the original `concurrentHashMap`, you have to call its constructor specifying the classes for the key/value pairs. I want to just simply be able to call the constructor `hashMap()`, without needing to specify those generics.

I've tried calling `super<class1, class2>();` in the constructor, but that gave me an error.

This seems like it should be something very simple, and I'm positive I used to know how to do this, but it's been a while and like I said I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks.

Comment: Really? I had a nagging feeling in the back of my head that there needed to be something else. But if you guys say that's how it works, then I'll take your word for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just plain `super();` will work—or nothing at all, since it is implied. Remember that `new HashMap<String,Integer>();` is not really a constructor invocation in the same sense of a method invocation: it is the specification of the type to instantiate + constructor arguments. The constructor itself **does not receive the type arguments**, they are there only as call-site type information.